# Viewing source code in pprof with bazel built binary

Tags: c++, profiling, bazel, pprof

I am trying to profile a binary that I've built under bazel using `pprof`. I am able to generate a profile, however when I view it in the web UI, I cannot see my code in the source code view. I see `??`s instead.

Here are the commands I'm using:

```sh
CPUPROFILE=/tmp/cpu_profile bazel run --linkopt='-lprofiler' //my:binary

pprof -http=localhost:8000 -lines bazel-bin/my/binary /tmp/cpu_profile
```

How can I access the source code information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, bazel builds binaries using the [fastbuild compilation_mode](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--compilation_mode) which doesn't have all of the necessary debug information needed to link the source.

To fix this, profile using `dbg` mode:

```sh
CPUPROFILE=/tmp/cpu_profile bazel run -c dbg \
  --linkopt='-lprofiler' \
  //my:binary
```

Or include debug information in an optimized build:

```sh
CPUPROFILE=/tmp/cpu_profile bazel run -c opt \
  --copt=-g \
  --linkopt='-lprofiler' \
  //my:binary
```